# Qt winId() forcing 32bit values

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Im trying to embed a display from an alien application (python OCC) into (Py)Qt using the winId of the widget. But when i pass it to  OCC i get an overflow error.
Inspecting the winId qt returns its 4318283408 which is more than a 32bit number. Im running 64bits (osx) and both libraries are compiled for 64bit, but i have a hunch that OCC only likes 32bit numbers still. So my question is, is there any way to control the range of the winId that Qt return?

Thanks

Henrik

Answer (score 0):

Looking in Qt's source code, in the file `src/gui/kernel/qwindowdefs.h`, you'll find that `WId` is typedef'd to `long` for 64-bits OSX (it's `int` for 32-bits OSX). A `long` on 64-bits OSX is 8 bytes long (or 64 bits), and therefore 4318283408 is a valid value.

If you want to force winId() to return a 32 bits value, you will need to link to a 32-bits version of the Qt's library.

Comment: Hmmm.. both libraries i use are 64 bit, but i suspect that 64bit port of OCC is not entirely 64bit-ready. Was hoping there might be some obscure setting in Qt that could modify the winId somehow? at least as a temporary hack